# Why can I not view my Google App Engine cron admin page?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron, stack-trace

When I go to http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin/cron, as stated in Google's docs, I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\__init__.py", line 501, in __call__
handler.get(*groups)
File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\admin\__init__.py", line 239, in get
schedule = groctimespecification.GrocTimeSpecification(entry.schedule)
File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\cron\groctimespecification.py", line 71, in GrocTimeSpecification
parser.period_string)
File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\cron\groctimespecification.py", line 122, in __init__
super(IntervalTimeSpecification, self).__init__(self)
TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
```

I have the latest SDK, and it looks like my config files are correct.

Answer (score 4):

This is definitely a bug in Google App Engine. If you check [groctimespecification.py](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/cron/groctimespecification.py?r=54#112), you'll see that `IntervalTimeSpecification` inherits from `TimeSpecification`, which in turn inherits directly from `object` and doesn't override its `__init__` method.

So the `__init__` of `IntervalTimeSpecification` is incorrect:

```
class IntervalTimeSpecification(TimeSpecification):
  def __init__(self, interval, period):
    super(IntervalTimeSpecification, self).__init__(self)
```

My guess is, someone converted an old-style parent class init call:

```
TimeSpecification.__init__(self)
```

to the current one, but forgot that with `super`, `self` is passed implicitly. The correct line should look like this:

```
super(IntervalTimeSpecification, self).__init__()
```

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations! You've found a bug. Can you file a bug on the [public issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list), please? If you want to fix it for yourself immediately, delete the 'self' argument in the line referenced at the end of that stacktrace.

Comment: Did you try that?  It didn't work for me, I think it's because I'm using 2.6, I'm downloading 2.5.4 right now to see if that fixes it.

Comment: No, I checked the source, and verified that it's definitely a bug. :)

Comment: For future reference, this has been fixed now (I'm on 1.2.8).